# How to select close icon in lightgallery with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I've tried to find an answer to the question, but there is no any.

So, I need to select the close icon in lightgallery with jquery like this $("").
http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/demos/ (this is just an example)

The close icon is a span and has a class "lg-close lg-icon",but for example if I try to change a background color

```
$(".lg-close.lg-icon").click(function(){$("p").css("background-color", "yellow");});
```

it doesn't work, because jquery can't find the span and its class in other words it can't see it because the span exists only when the gallery is open.
http://prntscr.com/kf2iwk (close icon)

Is there a way to select the close icon in lightgallery?

Comment: in the console what happens if you just enter ```$(".lg-close.lg-icon")```  ? if the selector is correct then it should find the element

Answer (score 0):

Replace Comma ( , ) with Colon ( : ) in the Code after "background-color" LIKE :

```
$(".lg-close.lg-icon").click(function(){
    $("p").css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

This will fix your Problem